# GET http://localhost:9000/content/radios/radio.wav 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, audio, jhipster

I want to play an audio file , i am using jhipster and in my angular application  i have loaded an image from the same directory where the radio.wav exists and it works .However when i try to play the audio the error apppears

GET http://localhost:9000/content/radios/radio.wav 404 (Not Found)

```
<audio controls >

        <source   src="http://localhost:9000/content/radios/radio.wav" type="audio/wav">
    </audio>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site.

Comment: how can i read an audio element from the localhost

Answer (score 1):

I think that your issue comes from webpack configuration. by default your audio file is bundled but you want to use it unbundled.

If you want to copy your audio file as-is you should configure the CopyWebpackPlugin in webpack/webpack.common.js

Comment: thank you for your answer but how can i configure the CopyWebpackPlugin?

Comment: Please read its doc https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin and edit the file I indicated